# Does the Data in UIPasteboard persist through system reboots?

Tags: ios, persistence, pasteboard

My question is very simple, I basically have 2 apps that want to access a pasteboard that I created for the 2 apps. What I want to know is lets say I saved a string to the pasteboard, and shut off the phone. When I restart the phone and open the 2nd app, will the string I saved before still be there?

I know pasteboards can be set to persistent by setting a property, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on the data within the pasteboards. So do data persist along with the pasteboard or do they disappear and only the pasteboard remain after a system restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does persist. Of course, you could try it yourself without code... Open the Notes app, type something, copy it. Reboot. Start Notes again (or whatever) and paste. It's still there...

Comment: Huh, I thought it would disappear, never had to reboot after copying something since I pasted right away. Thank then